# Simple way to get which image was clicked when running same function

Tags: android

I'm making a card game for android. You select your first card by clicking image1, second card by clicking image2, etc. These images run the same function in java, but how can I pass a variable to get that they clicked image1, image2, or image3? I'd like to avoid having 3 functions that are the exact same aside from one variable. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please provide clear explaination as well as some code, so that we can help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "images run the same function in java", but if you mean they all have the same OnClickListener then use [`getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) to determine which View was clicked.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.one:
        // Do something
        break;
    case R.id.two:
        // Do something
        break;
    }
}
```